# Create a table variable instance inline

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a custom table type and table function like so...

```
CREATE TYPE CustomTableType AS TABLE(
    Hello INT NULL
)    

ALTER function [dbo].[myfunc]
(
   @stuff CustomTableType READONLY
    
) RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN]
...
```

Is it possible to call this function without first declaring an instance of the table variable, in a view, for example, where that's not possible? e.g...

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc((SELECT Field1 FROM Table1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is **not**, you can't do that in this way. You need to insert values to a variable of that type outside the function. Even if your idea would be correct then still you need to have any strongly typed variable and `insert into` clause to put values in it (your subquery in function argument will still need to return something as instance of your `CustomTableType`, so there will be no difference between putting this batch inside the parentheses of the function call and outside them).